# Django urls href redirect bug

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

When I click on the "apropos" button on my navbar to access to my  "apropos" pages it load the page correctly but with this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/apropos/` when it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/apropos/`.

it does the samething when I click on the "contact" button on my navbar it redirect me to this urls `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/contact`

And when I click on "Accueil" it redirect me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact` 
When it should redirect me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("main.urls")),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("apropos/", include("main.urls")),
    path("contact/", include("main.urls")),
]
```

main/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    path("apropos/", views.apropos, name="apropos"),
    path("contact/", views.contact, name="contact")
]
```

views.py

```
def home(response):
    return render(response, "main/index.html", {})

def apropos(response):
    return render(response, "main/about.html", {})


def contact(response):
    return render(response, "main/contact.html", {})
```

index.html (navbar section)

```
<!-- header nav section -->
<header class="xs-header-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row  menu-item">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <nav id="navigation1" class="navigation header-nav clearfix">

                    <div class="nav-header">
                        <!--  <a class="nav-brand" href="#"></a>-->
                        <a href="./index.html" class="mobile-logo">
                            <img src="static/assets/images/mobile_logo.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="nav-toggle"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-menus-wrapper clearfix">
                        <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li class="active"><a href="{% url "home" %}">Home</a>
                           </li>
                           <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                           </li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "apropos" %}">À-propos</a></li>
                            <li>
                    <a href="{% url "contact" %}">Contact</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="header-nav-right-info align-to-right">
                            <label><i class="icon icon-phone3"></i> (514) 569-2380</label>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>

                </nav>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .row end -->
    </div><!-- .container end -->
</header><!-- End header nav section -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues that might be causing this.  One, your root urls.py should be like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("main.urls")),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Why?  the main urls.py will be appended to the ones in your root, and you should not have multiple `include("main.urls")` for the same path.

Second, you need to put single quotes in the anchor links, for example:

```html
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
```

Why? Because otherwise the double quotes would end after url, and then begin again after home.